# Access Server Side DataTable to javascript in asp.net MVC 3.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to access the dataTable created in MVC3.0 Controller to JavaScript without interaction of Html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. DataSets/DataTables were used in classic WebForms and are considered bad practice in ASP.NET MVC (in WebForms also IMHO but that's another topic).

In ASP.NET MVC you would be working with strongly typed models. So for example if you have a controller action which fetches a collection of some given model from a repository you could serialize it as JSON and use AJAX to fetch it from javascript:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    IEnumerable<MyModel> items = _repository.GetModel();
    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and then using jquery you could invoke this action:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("foo")', function(items) {
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        alert(item.Name);
    });
});
```

Another possibility is to have a controller action which returns a view and passes it a view model:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    IEnumerable<MyModel> items = _repository.GetModel();
    return View(items);
}
```

Then inside the corresponding view you could have a script which immediately consumes the model by serializing it directly to a JSON object inside the view using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var items = @MvcHtmlString.Create(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        alert(item.Name);
    });
</script>
```